# rewrite any combination of index.html

Tags: regex, apache, http, url, url-rewriting

I am interested in URL redirect of any letter case combination of index.html to all lowercase of index.html.

ie:

```
/foo/bar/INDEX.html
to 
/foo/bar/index.html

or

/hello/world/funk/indeX.HTML
to 
/hello/word/fund/index.html
```

I have tried couple regex but no luck. I am interested in Redirect only if there are any uppercase(s) in `index.html`

`/hello/there/index.html`
should not redirect anywhere.

I have access to httpd.conf hence I am using `RewriteMap lc int:tolower`

Comment: Probably the easiest/most straightforward regex would be `^(.*)[iI][nN][dD][eE][xX]\.[hH][tT][mM][lL]$`. However it does not fulfill the requirement to rewrite only and only if there is atleast 1 uppercase letter. It will match the lowercase `index.html` too. But I can't see why that would be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `(?!index\.html)(?i)index\.html(?-i)` it first checks if the string is not `index.html`, and then matches any string that is case insensitive `index.html`. Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/GNhAwG/1